# Recover deleted word document Help

Tags: icloud, ms-office, data-recovery, textedit, file-recovery

I Had a word document which I'm unsure where it was stored. It said my desktop but I believe it was also in my icloud somewhere. I saved my work and then emailed it to myself, after emailing the work I turned off the icloud which in turn deleted everything on my desktop. 
All I have is a textedit file whenever I attempt to click the document.

I'm unsure on whether the work is completely gone or still able to be recovered.
Time machine was not activated due to the macbook being new. Microsoft word didn't appear to do any backups or recover old files, there's nothing. It does show the file in recent but will not open or allow recovery. 
I have checked my icloud in the advanced section to try and recover files.. there is nothing there. 
In textedit I have tried to the 'revert' method which did not work.
I've followed multiple youtube tutorials and website searches to see if I can recover the work and still can't it's all dead ends.

Would a piece of software be able to take the short code from textedit and aid my recovery or is the work completely lost? This work has a deadline so I need to know whether it's worth trying to save or just restart.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You emailed it to yourself. Did you then delete the sent email? Just a thought...

Answer (score 1):

There are data recovery software packages for the Mac. These are not cheap but most offer a free trial. I used [Stellar Mac Data Recovery](https://recoverit.wondershare.net/ad/data-recovery.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIl8fQj-az6QIVTMaHCh2wRwB7EAEYASAAEgL0kPD_BwE) software and it found my file. They have a free trial.

Another one with good reviews is [EaseUs](https://www.easeus.com). It also has a free trial but recovery limited to 2 GB.  This [link](https://www.macworld.co.uk/feature/mac-software/best-data-recovery-apps-3681531/) also lists several others.

Some of them may find your file and then require you to buy the app in order to recover it. Most of these apps are around $100.

One I'd stay away from is Disk Drill. It maybe works fine but it is very intrusive. Popping open when you do various things.